# Chef-client throws 403 forbidden intermittently

Tags: chef-infra, http-status-code-403

I am using a brand new chef-server (not enterprise), and running chef-client throws a 403 forbidden error approximately every 1 out of 5 runs. Anyone know why this might occur?

- `chef-server 11.0.12` via getchef.com/chef/install
- `chef-client 11.12.4` via rubygem
- `ruby 2.1.2`
- `Debian Wheezy 7.5`

**The error:**

```
198.xx.xxx.xxx ================================================================================
198.xx.xxx.xxx Error executing action `create` on resource 'template[/var/www/mysite.com/shared/config/database.yml]'
198.xx.xxx.xxx ================================================================================
198.xx.xxx.xxx
198.xx.xxx.xxx Net::HTTPServerException
198.xx.xxx.xxx ------------------------
198.xx.xxx.xxx
198.xx.xxx.xxx 403 "Forbidden"
198.xx.xxx.xxx
198.xx.xxx.xxx
198.xx.xxx.xxx Resource Declaration:
198.xx.xxx.xxx
198.xx.xxx.xxx ---------------------
198.xx.xxx.xxx # In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/rails/recipes/production.rb
198.xx.xxx.xxx
198.xx.xxx.xxx  40: template node[:rails][:app_root]+"/shared/config/database.yml" do
198.xx.xxx.xxx  41:     owner "root"
198.xx.xxx.xxx  42:     group "xx-dev"
198.xx.xxx.xxx  43:     mode 0775
198.xx.xxx.xxx  44: end
198.xx.xxx.xxx  45:
198.xx.xxx.xxx
198.xx.xxx.xxx Compiled Resource:
198.xx.xxx.xxx
198.xx.xxx.xxx ------------------
198.xx.xxx.xxx
198.xx.xxx.xxx # Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/rails/recipes/production.rb:40:in `from_file'
198.xx.xxx.xxx
198.xx.xxx.xxx template("/var/www/mysite.com/shared/config/database.yml") do
198.xx.xxx.xxx   provider Chef::Provider::Template
198.xx.xxx.xxx   action "create"
198.xx.xxx.xxx   retries 0
198.xx.xxx.xxx   retry_delay 2
198.xx.xxx.xxx   path "/var/www/mysite.com/shared/config/database.yml"
198.xx.xxx.xxx   backup 5
198.xx.xxx.xxx   source "database.yml.erb"
198.xx.xxx.xxx   cookbook_name "rails"
198.xx.xxx.xxx   recipe_name "production"
198.xx.xxx.xxx   mode 509
198.xx.xxx.xxx   owner "root"
198.xx.xxx.xxx   group "xx-dev"
198.xx.xxx.xxx end
198.xx.xxx.xxx
198.xx.xxx.xxx [2014-05-29T20:16:34+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
198.xx.xxx.xxx [2014-05-29T20:16:34+00:00] FATAL: Saving node information to /var/chef/cache/failed-run-data.json
198.xx.xxx.xxx [2014-05-29T20:16:34+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
198.xx.xxx.xxx [2014-05-29T20:16:34+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
198.xx.xxx.xxx [2014-05-29T20:16:34+00:00] FATAL: Net::HTTPServerException: template[/var/www/mysite.com/shared/config/database.yml] (rails::production line 40) had an error: Net::HTTPServerException: 403 "Forbidden"
```

Comment: How many nodes are you using?

Comment: I have approximately 50, Mr. Vargo.

Comment: Is this a long running recipe?

Comment: Long running? This is my most extensive cookbook for sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Objects from cookbooks (`template`s, `cookbook_file`s) are lazily-loaded by default.

If it's a very long run, and it sounds like it is, then the runtime might exceed the maximum time window enforced by the server from the original authentication.

You can turn off lazy loading on the client by adding

`no_lazy_load true`

to your client.rb. See http://docs.opscode.com/config_rb_client.html

Comment: How can you set this during the bootstrap process?

Comment: This did NOT work for me. I still get the 403 error in spite of no_lazy_load true in my client.rb file

Comment: Are you running your own Chef server?

Comment: Julian, yes I am. I found a solution where I had to increase a url timeout value on my server from 900 to 1800 and that worked.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Julian's answer, this worked for me when we ran recipes that took over 15 minutes. 15 mins is the default TTL value for the Chef server:

Edit app.config file under `/var/opt/chef-server/erchef/etc` or `/opt/opscode/embedded/service/opscode-erchef/etc` depending on the version of Chef you have installed.

Set the `s3_url_ttl` value to something more than 900 seconds. We used 3600 to get around the problem and then rebooted the Chef server host.